# Show that if $T(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt $, then $T(1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to calculate the following

Given:

$ T(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt $

I need to show that $ T(1)=1 $

Solution:

My logic was to plug $1$ in for $x$ before I integrated, but I am not sure if I can do that

So,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{1-1}dt=-e^{-t}\vert_0^\infty,$$ which gives me a final answer of 1

Comment: Good job! What is your question?

Comment: Iam not sure if I can plug 1 in for x before I integrate so I am not sure if my answer is correct

Comment: @javahelper123 That's how a function works

Comment: Okay so that is good for my answer? Just seemed way to easy

Comment: @javahelper123 Yeah, looks good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is correct, indeed, in general if we have $T(x) = \int_{a}^b f(x, t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ then $T(1)$ is given by $\int_a^b f(1, t) \, \mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the edit. :-)